# SSIS: Go back to prior step when If-condition is not met

Tags: if-statement, ssis

I build a workflow in SSIS. 
At two steps this workflow is checking an `If`-Condition.

If the result is `true`, the workflow should continue.

If it is `false` the workflow should go back to prior step and start over.

It is clear to me how to implement the If-Condition. But how can I **redirect** the control flow **to a prior step**? If I just link one node to the prior node I am getting following error.
[image]

Is there any special node for this issue? Did anyone have a similar problem and knows the solution?

Comment: This can be achieved by putting the "prior step" and the "if condition" inside a For Loop container, and chceking the "if condition" inside the For Loop Container. Then the two steps will continue to run untile the condition is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add an example here for others as well. In this example I use control flow. This control flow contains: 
1. Two script task 'Task 1' and 'Task 2' which at the moment only have a MessageBox.Show to display the corresponding task name. 
2. One Expression Task checking the if condition. 
3. A for loop continuing based on an expression. 
4. A package Boolean variable named 'Flag' which is set initially to True.

The SSIS package looks like below: 
[image]

The for loop expression looks like below:
[image]
And, the expression for expression task looks like below: 
[image]

The variable Flag can be changed in script task 1 for some special conditions or can be changed by some other means as required. In that case, the loop will exit and start running the task 2, otherwise task 1 will be continued.